# Benhmarking CPU usage: Synchronous vs Asynchronous HTTP clients

Tags: http, asynchronous, benchmarking, cpu-usage, synchronous

I have been performing some benchmarks on my system, and one thing I have been looking at more closely is the behaviour of my program which performs a number of HTTP calls over time. To be more specific, what I have is a microservice which pumps out synchronous HTTP calls on request. I decided to stress test this by injecting some load into my system which will in turn trigger the microservice to perform one synchronous HTTP call after another. (Each call requires about 1s to return a response i.e. blocked for 1s).

It turns out that the CPU usage is dominated by this part of the program. Where other parts occupy 5-10% of the CPU usage over time, this part occupies as much as a 50% constant over time which is a massive difference and clear bottleneck.

My question is, if I rerun this test with an asynchronous HTTP client, can I see such massive consumption of CPU by my HTTP calls? Since the HTTP call still will need 1s to return a response, won't it put high load on the CPU for polling to check that a response is returned? Or will it ask for much less load from the CPU since one thread can handle more work? What will the CPU usage look like over time?

Comment: Why don't you run this test first and ask a question after you need help interpreting the results?

Comment: How about profiling first? You neither state OS, language or anything specfic here. It is impossible to give any meaningful answer here. I am 100% sure that the bottleneck is not what you did assume so far if you did not profile it.

Answer (score 2):

In the first part you have mentioned that

> I decided to stress test this by injecting some load into my system
> which will in turn trigger the microservice to perform one synchronous
> **HTTP call after another**. (Each call requires about 1s to return a
> response i.e. blocked for 1s).

and after that "this part occupies as much as a 50% constant over time".

### Repeated HTTP Calls Occupy More CPU Time and Thread Creation Time

#### Cpu Usage behind Process

What made this CPU usage is not polling, it's **context switching** and **thread creation.**

When the application runs repeated HTTP calls, it creates multiple threads like in Network Diver. And each thread lasts about **1 second** before it finishes.

[image: Histogram: Process launch dominates over thread launch over context switching etc]

Each thread launch and context switch gets CPU time, and when you do them **in a row** it can be like running an infinite loop `while(true)`
but if it was fully sequential task like an infinite loop it would occupy one CPU core.

#### Asynch Tasks make Parallel Cores Busier

So what did happen?

Creating threads from your script is not a sequential task. It gets parallel.

Cecause your script does this within a loop in a sequential manner:

```
while(true){
    create_http_request();
}
```

Suppose this function call leads to a system call to create a thread:

```
function create_network_socket(){
    @syscall.createThread();
}
```

and suppose your script `create_http_request()` takes about 1 us to call an async call to system call.

So it can iterate about *a million* times in 1 second (to a thread close).

But in each call, the script calls an operating system syscall for a job (creating a thread).

Suppose it takes 5 us.

So this will be what's happening here in a second:

- A sequential task from your script runs with 1 CPU core.
- It asks for a million jobs from the operating system, which requires 4,000,000 us of CPU time to complete.
- And it requires 5 additional CPU cores to perform the job asynchronously.

It leave you with 6 fully loaded cores.

#### Inverse Relation Bottleneck

Asynchronous between HTTP request script and system calls makes it possible to have parallel jobs. That's what leads to this 50% CPU usage.

The bottleneck of running stimulus tasks were sequentially invoking HTTP requests.

So the quicker it gets, it performs more HTTP requests per second, and so it consumes more CPU for other parts (operating system) to do the job.

So it seems to have an inverse relation bottleneck.

### The Http Async Request

#### What Happens in Data Flow

When a script request an HTTP call, what happens can be seen as a data flow from the script to the destination and returning back. I am going to illustrate it with some simple steps to discuss later:

```
script function call
--> framework/lib function call
    --> interpreter/module call
        --> OS socket lib call
            --> OS system call
                --> driver call
                    --> hardware invocation (NIC)
                        --> physical media buffering and signalling
```

In this flow you can consider some nodes and some links.

Depending on the technology, every link can be half-duplex or full duplex.  And every node can be implemented using different technology as we get to it later.

But what happens in the low level layer of our Von Neumann architecture and our CPU running sequential machine code with jump functionality?

These codes will be run after another, and the only way the could get notified from data changes are 2:

- They check for a location: **polling** as you mentioned
- Other signals **interrupt** their work and notify them. (Needs additional signal link)

When one of the above node (script, driver, any function call) needs data to work with, and data is not ready, it should wait until data becomes available, at which point it gets informed using polling or an interrupt.

But when data is not ready yet it can behave in 2 distinct ways:

- Blocking: sync. The thread waits for data and pass the CPU to OS for another process.
- Non-blocking: async. The thread waits for data. But another thread starts to execute another part which doesn't require this data.

#### Sync and Async in every Node

Every node in that flow chain has its own mechanism to link with other nodes in the chain. Every individual node can act *(sync or async)* with others and every link can get response (with *polling* or *interruption).*

For example:

Even you run a sync HTTP request to a server, your driver won't be blocking for other jobs.

In some links it can be an interruption, like a NIC can receive a signal from two RX wire over Ethernet, or it can be polling like a thread polling the IPC Pipe.

#### Conclusion

If you invoke HTTP request asynchronously, the other nodes in the data flow chain will act the same as before (most of them async) (depending on program/technology).

And the links remain the same.

The only difference is in your benchmark script.

If you have another `Foo` jobs in your script it can be performed:

- Blocking: after HTTP response
- Non-blocking: after HTTP request call

It doesn't matter whether you have other jobs.

#### Long Run

Because the benchmark is a loop of 1 second of stateless job, after 1 seconds it's no difference two perform **Foo Job** after requests or after responses.

Comment: I tried to clean up your formatting and English but I have no idea what the "Long Run" sentence at the end is trying to say.

Comment: Do you mean *priority inversion?*

Comment: Thanks for editing. The Question Asked if it can gained performance (cpu usage) if it implemented via async method. and  **by Long Run** i meant for limit to infinite run. in this case **more than 1 second**  it dosent differ

Comment: So something like "Because the benchmark is a loop of stateless jobs with a 1-second duration, there is no way to make an individual job run faster ...?"

Answer (score 0):

Async calls can delegate the work to the OS, of course networking is one of these cases.
[This link from microsoft.com is about .net yet is valid for any async capable framework/language](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/async-in-depth)

> Although work is executed in some context (that is, the OS does have to pass data to a device driver and respond to an interrupt), there is no thread dedicated to waiting for data from the request to come back. This allows the system to handle a much larger volume of work rather than waiting for some I/O call to finish.

Assuming that your microservice runs on top of such a language/framework it will for sure benefit of async calls because of not wasting threads that spend most of the time idle but that still are a cost both on memory and cpu.

Though you could still see massive cpu consumption.

One http call at a time can not put that much pressure on cpu, so multiple requests to your system must trigger parallel sequences of http request to be able to hog the cpu. If we take out of the equation the efficiency of the code and there is no parsing/elaboration in this code then is the processing of the network data that is actually consuming cpu.

A way of reducing cpu pressure from networking is enable tcp-offloading and other available "offloadings" to the network interface if supported.

[tcp offloading wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_offload_engine)

> TCP offload engine (TOE) is a technology used in network interface cards (NIC) to offload processing of the entire TCP/IP stack to the network controller. It is primarily used with high-speed network interfaces, such as gigabit Ethernet and 10 Gigabit Ethernet, where processing overhead of the network stack becomes significant.

Though I would not straight away assume that a cpu usage of 50% is the clear bottleneck, it means that the cpu is being used more, you have to perform tests and measure